# Ignoring rest of SQL query

Tags: sql, comments

I have got query like this :

```
Select id, article from articles
where article="article"
order by id;
```

I want to ignore everything after first line, i already tried adding # after "from articles", but it did not work.

Comment: comments in SQL are  `--` add it before each line you want to comment out

Comment: Tag dbms used. ANSI SQL has double quotes for delimited identifiers, so this means `where where article = article`, which is the same as `where article is not null`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand question correctly, you just want comment out all lines after first. It may be done with adding --:

```
Select id, article from articles
-- where article="article"
-- order by id;
```

### Update by comment what only first line may be edit

SQL does not offer such possibility, but you may use some trick like:

```
Select id, article from articles; SELECT 1 FROM (SELECT Null article, Null id) t
where article="article 2"
order by id;
```

You may try that example on sql fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/00106/8/0

Comment: Exactly, but i only have access to the first line, so i cannot add -- to all lines below, there is too many of them. I need to do it from the 1st line.

Comment: What RDBMS you are use?

Comment: I've update my answer in assumption what only one first line may be edited.

Answer (score 0):

select id, article from articles
where article="$article"
order by id limit 1;